# Is there any difference between use Entity Framework in C# and VB.net?

Tags: c#, vb.net, entity-framework

I'm using Visual Basic as a programming language and Entity Framework. I would like to know if there is any difference between using Entity Framework for VB.NET and C#, because whenever I search for something from Entity Framework, I find it in C#, even the Entity Framework documentation itself comes with examples in C#.

Thank you

Comment: Entity Framework is exactly the same. You will find c# examples far outnumber vb.net examples for everything, not just EF.

Comment: Behind the scenes it the same code running, VB.Net and C# are both using the same .Net DLLs to handle EF, and everything else. C# is now the dominant .Net language, with MS saying it's the language to use, with VB.Net essentially being relegated to an educational role. Thankfully it's generally really easy to convert C# code to VB.Net, with a few exceptions. In future though, you're probably best doing any new development in C# if you have the choice.

Comment: The only differences I've seen is in the Early Binding and Late Bindings.  VB will more often recognize objects dynamically than in c#.

Comment: Thank you all( Crowcoder, Slugsie and Jdweng ) , I understand.